# How can I know with Aegean Airlines if I have Economy Light or Economy ComfortFlex fare?

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, fare-class, aegean-airlines

I bought my tickets from Heraklion (HER) to Bilbao (BIO) with EDreams. I have three flights HER-ATH, ATH-FRA and FRA-BIO, and my first two are with Aegean Airlines. The only information I have is that I am "Economy Class" but, inside this, I can not find if I have "Light" or "ComfortFlex" fare for my hand-baggage. Where should I check this? I have bought 1 checked-in baggage (23kg) but I need to know my hand baggage.

Answer (score 5):

If EDreams supplied you with a PNR (Aegean's 6-digit booking record number), use that number on [Aegean Airlines' website](https://en.aegeanair.com/plan/my-booking/) to retrieve your booking details.

If EDreams didn't send you the PNR, then ask EDreams to provide it, and/or [ask Aegean to retrieve your booking information](https://en.aegeanair.com/resend-booking-confirmation-email/).

When you have the PNR, retrieve your booking information from [Aegean's webpage](https://en.aegeanair.com/plan/my-booking/) to see the details. If the details are not shown, then you could do any of the following:

- Contact Aegean and ask them, using any of the methods listed on Aegean's [Contacts Page](https://en.aegeanair.com/contact/): using Aegean's online Contact Form, Social Media (Messenger and Twitter), or telephone (number depends on where you're calling from).
- Go to an airport served by Aegean and walk up to the counter and ask Aegean staff for assistance.

Comment: I have already tried with that but inside Aegean the only information I get is Economy, no more

Comment: @Jonebil See expanded answer.

Comment: @Jonebil be aware that if you bought through a third party, you might not have either Light or ComfortFlex - you may have an Economy fare tailored exactly for eDreams.